# Choosing item from drop down list then grabbing the Item's ID C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello I have a view page that looks like this

```
@model PIC_Program_1._0.Models.Shipping
@using PIC_Program_1._0.Models;

@{
    PIC_Program_1_0Context db = new PIC_Program_1_0Context();

    Model.preparedBy = Model.preparedBy != null  ? Model.preparedBy : IGT.user;

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()   
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="3">Items</th>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", })

                        @{ 
                             Item i = db.Items.Find(int.Parse(Request["ItemID"]));

                             var packedItems = Model.packed(i);
                             var orderedItems = Model.SalesOrder.totalItems(i);

                             var itemMax = orderedItems - packedItems;
                         }

                    </td>                       
                    <td>

                      <input type="number" value="@ViewBag.ItemQ" name="item_qty" class="form-control" max="@itemMax" />

                    </td>

                </tr>
```

I want the user to be able to choose the item from the dropdown, then I want to grab the item that the user selected and I want it to put it into the method parameter

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible with C# function. Once the web page has been rendered and displayed, you can't run any more C# code. You're going to need javascript/jquery for this one.

Answer (score 0):

On the backend

string strDDLValue = Request.Form["ddlVendor"].ToString();

you can view this in debug to help

```
@Html.DropDownList("ItemsXY", new SelectList(ViewBag.ItemsXY), "Choose Category", new { @class = "form-control" })

$("#ItemsXY").on("change", function () {
 var q = $("#Category").val();

console.log("val = " + q);
});
```

---

In your form collection

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PIC_Program_1(SomeViewModel someMV,FormCollection form)
{           
  string strDDLValue = form["ItemsXY"].ToString();    
  return View(MV);
}
```

or

```
string strDDLValue = Request.Form["ItemsXY"].ToString();
```

---

If you need the *text of selected item as well*, add a hidden field and on drop down selection change set selected item text in the hidden field:

Update your model to hold hidden values

```
// Add this to your VM
public string SelectItemsXY {get;set;}
public string SelectedItemsXYText { get; set; }

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#ItemsXY").on("change", function {
   $("#SelectedvendorText").val($(this).text());
 });
});
</script>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedItemsXY , Model.ItemsXY, "Select ItemsXY")
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedItemsXYText)
```